# Problem importing database - import hangs on exp_stash table

Tags: stash, database, mysql, database-error, database-migrations

**Here's a weird one.** I need to set up a dev server, so I'm importing a DB from and existing production EE install. The import proceeds fine until it gets to the exp_stash table. Then I get MySQL error 150. I've tried this on two different servers, but I get the same error.

```
CREATE TABLE  `exp_stash` (
`id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`site_id` INT( 4 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '1',
`session_id` VARCHAR( 40 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`bundle_id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '1',
`key_name` VARCHAR( 64 ) NOT NULL ,
`key_label` VARCHAR( 64 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`created` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`expire` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
`parameters` TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ) ,
KEY  `bundle_id` (  `bundle_id` ) ,
KEY  `key_session` (  `key_name` ,  `session_id` ) ,
KEY  `key_name` (  `key_name` ) ,
KEY  `site_id` (  `site_id` ) ,
CONSTRAINT  `exp_stash_fk` FOREIGN KEY (  `bundle_id` ) REFERENCES    
`exp_stash_bundles` (  `id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 ROW_FORMAT = COMPACT;
```

The error is

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'versastu_oakcrk.exp_stash' (errno: 150)
```

Research shows it has something to do with InnoDB table type/db type, but solution is unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular quandary, this worked:

Add this line to the top of the SQL file:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Source: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/stash/viewthread/5700

If you see this problem and the above solution doesn't work, check this thread as well:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/stash/viewthread/10311